# Is "He ensured to lock the door" correct English usage?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality

It's not clear to me from a dictionary if this is correct verb tense use of the word 'ensure'. Something about it doesn't sound right, but I can't see why it would be incorrect. Ensure in this usage:

"He ensured to lock the door."
"She sometimes ensured to kick him."

When I run it through an online grammar checker it says that the grammar is correct.

I came across these contextually similar internet examples:
"In office, he ensured to create opportunities for Black people and to address issues of employment"
"Beowulf was great. He ensured to stay true to his word and thank God for his fate"

Comment: It's not correct usage. One would use _He was sure to lock the door_ instead.

Comment: Or _He ensured that the door was locked_ meaning that he checked to make sure (and locked it himself if it wasn't). _She ensured to kick him_ doesn't make sense - I'm not clear what you intend it to mean.

Comment: The definition of ensure is listed as "to make sure" but you cannot simply replace "made sure" with "ensured" in all cases. It is beyond me to explain why, but that's the way it is and probably the root of your confusion. The internet examples appear to be improper usage.

Answer (score 1):

As John Lawler said, it is incorrect. You should say "He was sure to lock the door" or "He made sure to lock the door".